# Dealing with total derivative in Euler Equation

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to solve this:

$I = \int_0^1(x^2-y^2-(y')^2)$ using the euler equation:
 $\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}]-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =0$

and find the function y(x). So, I have:

$\frac{d}{dx}[2y']-2y=0$. How do I deal with the $\frac{d}{dx}$? Re-writing it in some form of partial derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how

> $$ \frac{d}{dx}[2y']-2y=0 \implies 2y''-2y=0\implies y''(x)-y(x)=0. $$

Now what's left is to solve the last ode.

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I was thinking that an x derivative would interact strangely with y'. Thanks.

Comment: @CINA: It happens sometimes that we miss things. You have done a good job. Good luck. You are welcome.